# Pass Parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Following code returns a stored procedure with a hard value coded. I need to allow 74(@catcode in Stored Procedure) to change to whatever is selected from a combo box. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using a pass through query in Access.

```
Private Sub ok_Click()

Dim objConnection As New ADODB.Connection

Dim objCom As ADODB.Command

Dim provStr As String

Dim objConnection As New ADODB.Connection

Dim objCom As ADODB.Command

Dim provStr As String

Set objCom = New ADODB.Command

objConnection.Provider = "sqloledb"

provStr = "Data Source=***;" & "Initial Catalog=***;User Id=***;Password=***;"

objConnection.Open provStr


With objCom

.ActiveConnection = objConnection

.CommandText = "dbo.ix_spc_planogram_match " & ("@catcode=") & Me.cat_code.Value

.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

.Parameters.Refresh     

.Parameters("@catcode").Value = me.cat_code.value 
   .Execute

    End With

    End Sub
```

Stored Procedure:

```
execute dbo.ix_spc_planogram_match @catcode
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you mean something on these lines:

```
.CommandText = "dbo.ix_spc_planogram_match " &  me.cat_code
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.cmd.Parameters("@catcode") =  me.cat_code

.Execute
```

This is assuming that the bound column of the combo contains the required value.